# Cucumber pass value between operation files

Tags: java, cucumber

So I have java files:

```
AuthorizationSteps.java
     AuthorizationOperation.java

UserSteps.java
   UserOperation.java
```

in `AuthorizationOperation.java` I'm obtaning a token using method `String token = getToken()` and passing to `AuthorizationSteps.java` as returned value. Then using pico container
 `scenarioContext.setContext("token", token)`; in `AuthorizationSteps.java` I'm saving a token.

Then in `UserSteps.java`: I'm passing  `scenarioContext.getContext("token")`; token value to a method as parameter in `UserOperation.java.`   and this scenario works for me.

The question is: Is this possible to pass token from  `AuthorizationOperation.java` to  `UserOperation.java`?

Each time when I try:
`ScenarioContext scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext`;  in `UserOperation.java` and `AuthorizationOperation.java`  I'm getting null token value

Comment: Did you read https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/?lang=java ?

Comment: yes, I pass state between stepDefs via ScenarioContext class, as is mentioned here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-picocontainer  in Belly.java example

but I share state between stepDefs class, not operation.java classes

Comment: Okay. Then you should inject `ScenarioContext` into your operation classes. So don't use `new ScenarioContext` but let pico container inject it into the operation class. This also means you shouldn't use `new *Operation` in your `*Steps` classes.